# The role of initial state of lstm layer in seq2seq encoder

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, machine-translation, seq2seq

I am trying to follow this guide to implement a seq2seq machine tranlsation model: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention

The tutorial's `Encoder` has an `initialize_hidden_state()` function that is used to generate all 0 as initial state for the encoder. However I am a bit confused as to why this is neccessary. As far as I can tell, the only times when `encoder` is called (in train_step and evaluate), they were initialized with the `initialize_hidden_state()` function. My questions are 1.) what is the purpose of this initial state? Doesn't Keras layer automatically initialize LSTM states to begin with? And 2.) why not always just initialize the `encoder` with all 0 hidden states if encoder is always called with initial states generated by `initialize_hidden_state()`?

Comment: SO is meant for coding questions. For questions about machine learning theory, there is [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) and [Data Science StackExchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are totally right. The code in the example is a little misleading. The LSTM cells are automatically initialized with zeros. You can just delete the `initialize_hidden_state()` function.